# Update when third character is "_"

Tags: mysql

I want to update column 1 in table A in a specific way: When the third character in the column is an "_" I want to insert the first 2characters, if the third character anythin else I want to leave it as it is.

Example:

```
|col1|                     
+--------+
|161_512 |       
|16_1217 |  
|161_512 |      
|161512  |         
|17_0117 |
|1615_12 |
```

Expected outcome:

```
|col1|                     
+--------+
|161_512 |       
|16      |  
|161_512 |      
|161512  |         
|17      |
|1615_12 |
```

Thats what I´ve got so far - but this is not working correctly:

```
UPDATE table A SET col1 = CASE WHEN col1 LIKE '%_%' THEN ... ELSE  col1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match a literal underscore in your `LIKE` expression, you will need to escape it using backslash.  An unescaped underscore means match any single character.  However, I would reword your query such that it uses a `WHERE` clause to determine whether or not to update a given record.

```
UPDATE table A
SET col1 = ...
WHERE col1 LIKE '__\_%'
```

Note carefully here that `LIKE __\_%` says to match any two characters, followed by a literal underscore, followed by anything else.

If you don't feel comfortable dealing with all this, you can always use a substring to check the value of the third character:

```
UPDATE table A
SET col1 = ...
WHERE SUBSTRING(col1, 3, 1) = '_'
```

Comment: +1 Just beat me to it. According to [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html), `_` is a wildcard that matches exactly one character.

Answer (score 1):

> When the third character in the column is an "_" I want to insert the first 2characters

I don't know what this means. First 2 characters from which attribute? Where do you want to insert them?

> When the third character in the column is an "_"

That's simple. As you may already know, the underscore character is a wildcard matching exactly one character. Hence

```
LIKE '%_%'
```

will match any attribute with a at least one character. If you explicitly want to match an underscore character then you would escape the underscore

```
LIKE '%\_%'
```

And to require this to be the third character, perform a match on 2 single characters before it:

```
LIKE '__\_%'
```

(L I K E ' _ _ \ _ ')